# As3 ios performance when dealing with large object/MC

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad

This might be a simple question to answer, but I'm asking it anyway.

In my iPad app scene i have a rather large draggable MC which holds 30 tiled nested MCs. Each of the nested children are animating. Now my question is whether to add all of the 30 MCs in the parent MC at once, or to only add them once they are within the boundaries of the screen?

The parent MC is draggable so there will only be 4-6 child MCs within the screen viewport.

So will it slow down the performance if I add all 30 MC's to the parent MC at once? Or does it only deal with the animated MCs once they are within the screen?

Cheers.

Comment: Supposedly deep movie clip hierarchies also slow performance. Might not be the case here, but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Movieclips added to stage, but outside the screen viewport will cost performance but less than within the viewport. Why don't you remove the parent MC from stage when this MC is outside the viewport?

Also 30 animated nested (vector) Movieclips are quite heavy on lower devices. For performance optimalisation you may convert vector art to bitmap in the Flash IDE, play with movieclip.cacheAsBitmap property or blitting your animation (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/blitting_mc.html).

Overall for good performance with lots of visuals take a look at http://gamua.com/starling/

Comment: Great, thanks. Had a look at (and actually implemented the Starling framework in FB). However this causes a new problem. The ability to nest MCs into parent MC is not possible in the framework. And since I need to have a parent MC (so ALL child MCs are dragged, when dragging the parent MC), I guess Starling does not help much. Also I've tested the dragging of a Quad, and it seems to lag and not be precise at all.

Comment: I'm nor sure why you think you can't nest movieclips in Starling. You can use the addChild on a Sprite and animate the sprite with tweeners (http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/movie_clips). For complex animations in Starling have a look at http://dragonbones.github.io/. I think the lag in dragging Quads / Sprites in Starling is not that much . See http://gamua.com/starling/first-steps/# open the demo on 'multitouch' for an example

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stefan :) i'll have a go at the textureAtlas (when creating a movieclip. But I will have 27 different, tiled MovieClips. All animating. However the screen will only hold about 6 of them at a time. It's sort of like a "where's wally" game, where the user has to drag the 27 MCs and find one particular MC. Will this be too much for the Ipad/iphone to process? (27 texture atlasses)?